# C++ regex behavior

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, c++14

I have check this simple regex test in regexr or regexpal :
**\"[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+\"[\s]*:[\s]*([0-9]*1[0-9]*|\"[a-zA-Z_0-9:\s-\,./\=;]*1[a-zA-Z_0-9:\s-\,./\=;]*\")**

text :
*"dataStoreMaxConns" : 100,
               "dataStoreName" : "cofax",
               "dataStorePassword" : "dataStoreTestQuery",
               "dataStoreTestQuery" : "SET NOCOUNT ON;select test='test';",
               "dataStoreUrl" : "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=goon"*

Result : 2 matches

1. "dataStoreMaxConns" : 100
2. "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=goon"

I have try with c++ any in https://wandbox.org/ and vs2010 standalone:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

//using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string format_1;
    std::string main,dig,phrase;
    std::ifstream infile("noname-2");
    if(infile.good()==false)
        return false;



    main="\\\"[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+\\\"[\\s]*:[\\s]*";
    dig="[0-9]*1[0-9]*";
    phrase="\\\"[a-zA-Z_0-9:\\s\\-\\,\\.\/\\=;]*1[a-zA-Z_0-9:\\s\\-\\,\\.\/\\=;]*\\\"";

    format_1=main+"("+dig+"|"+phrase+")";
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    std::regex f_1(format_1,std::regex_constants::icase);

    std::smatch m_1;
    for(auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), f_1);it != std::sregex_iterator();++it)
    {
         std::cout<<it->str()<<std::endl;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

nonname-2 contains the ***text***

Result is only one: *"dataStoreMaxConns" : 100*

Why?

Comment: Remove the unnecessary escapes and place `-` always at the start/end of the character class - https://ideone.com/3GQRiE

Comment: Raw string might help `"("[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+"\s*:\s*)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove unnecessary escape symbols and make sure the `-` symbol is placed at the start/end of the character class (when escaped, in C++ std::regex does not really handle it as a literal char).

Use

```
std::string main2="\"[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+\"\\s*:\\s*";
std::string dig="[0-9]*1[0-9]*";
std::string phrase="\"[a-zA-Z_0-9:\\s,./=;\\\\-]*1[a-zA-Z_0-9:\\s,./=;\\\\-]*\"";
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/3GQRiE):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string main2="\"[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+\"\\s*:\\s*";
    std::string dig="[0-9]*1[0-9]*";
    std::string phrase="\"[a-zA-Z_0-9:\\s,./=;\\\\-]*1[a-zA-Z_0-9:\\s,./=;\\\\-]*\"";

    std::string format_1=main2+"("+dig+"|"+phrase+")";
    std::string str("\"dataStoreMaxConns\" : 100,\n\"dataStoreName\" : \"cofax\",\n\"dataStorePassword\" : \"dataStoreTestQuery\",\n\"dataStoreTestQuery\" : \"SET NOCOUNT ON;select test='test';\",\n\"dataStoreUrl\" : \"jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=goon\"");
    std::regex f_1(format_1,std::regex_constants::icase);

    std::smatch m_1;
    for(auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), f_1);it != std::sregex_iterator();++it)
    {
         std::cout<<it->str()<<std::endl;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Raw string might help `"("[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+"\s*:\s*)"`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, why not, it is best practice ([and works well](https://ideone.com/nqvkFA)). Just the main issue is that the `-` should be placed at the end of the character class.

Comment: Thanks! But with the fourth example from json.org/example.html,  _'\"dataStoreUrl\" : \"jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=goon\"'_ is not detected. what can be the reason?

Comment: You have `\/\/` - you need to match ``\`` chars, too. Fix [as shown here](https://ideone.com/T3tayf).